# Apache Nifi: Removing multiple columns from a csv

Tags: java, csv, apache-nifi

> I have a csv with **over 60 columns**. Yet I only **want just 32 columns** out of the initial csv. (My csv has headings)

I used a `QueryRecord` Processor and added a `CSVReader` and a `CSVRecordSetWriter`. Then I added a new property named `done` and assigned the following SQLstatement as the value.

`SELECT col1, col2, col9, col18, ..... col65 FROM FlowFile`

The above statement has all the names (this situation col1, col2 etc are the names of the columns) of the 32 columns I want in the output csv.

This failed since I received the following error. According to my understanding this is due to **exceeding a limit of supported columns**. Since this method works if I want unto 7-8 columns.

[image: error]

Hope you can suggest me a processor or a nifi workflow, which I can take the 32 columns out of the 65 columns successfully.

***I tried for 15 and it works. Therefore I tried for 16 columns and it works. So I tried for 15 again and then even that doesn't work. The error seems inconsistent.***

Answer (score 2):

Can you share the full error from the log? The actual cause will be after the text you shared from the bulletin/error. I'm not sure if the table name is case sensitive but I recommend `FLOWFILE` as the table name just in case.

Also if you know the input schema ahead of time, you could just use ConvertRecord and set your CSVRecordSetWriter's schema to be like the input schema but with only the field names (columns) you want. ConvertRecord won't output fields that don't exist in the output schema, which has the affect of removing those fields and keeping only the ones you want.

If you don't know the schema, then QueryRecord should work (depending on what error you're facing)

Comment: I tried editing the schema accordingly. But there seems to be a limit since it's said to be invalid after about 17 columns.

Comment: Can you share the error? I'm not sure why there'd be an error with so few columns

Comment: Can you try executing the a sql statement